# How can I build kinematicPTP block from trapezoidal speed profile?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

How can I build a kinematicPTP block from this speed profile?

It's a trapezoidal profile with acceleration, constant velocity and deceleration phase. In particular :

- Acceleration Time : 10 s
- Start speed ( at time = 0 s ) : 0 rad/s
- Speed at 10 s : 47.1 rad/s --> Acceleration : 4.71 rad/s^2
- Constant speed time : 5 s ( at 47.1 rad/s )
- Deceleration Time : 3 s
- End Speed : 0 rad/s --> Deceleration : 15.7 rad/s^2

I'm trying to use Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Trapezoid but I can't build deceleration phase.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two possibilities using either [Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Trapezoid](http://doc.modelica.org/om/Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable.html) or [Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable](http://doc.modelica.org/om/Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Trapezoid.html).

```
model M1
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Trapezoid trapezoid(
    amplitude=47.1,
    rising=10,
    width=5,
    falling=3,
    period=18,
    nperiod=1)
    annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-80,60},{-60,80}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable combiTimeTable(
    table=[0,0;10,47.1;15,47.1;18,0],
    extrapolation=Modelica.Blocks.Types.Extrapolation.HoldLastPoint)
    annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-80,20},{-60,40}})));
  annotation(experiment(StopTime=20), uses(Modelica(version="3.2.2")));
end M1;
```